# Background thread confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, performselector

I'm trying to improve the responsiveness of my app but am a complete newbie to threading and have become confused.

On launch an alert is shown:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSString *user = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
        NSString *pass = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1] text];
        [self loginToServerWithUsername:user andPassword:pass];
    }
}
```

within the `loginToServerWithUsername:` method, the app calls a method:

```
[self checkFiles:sessionID];
```

This can take several seconds so I tried to execute it in the background:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                        [self checkFiles:sessionID];
                    });
```

checkFiles method:

```
fileList = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

NSArray *directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *downloadsFolderString = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DOWNLOADS_FOLDER];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString* file;
NSDirectoryEnumerator* enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:downloadsFolderString];
while (file = [enumerator nextObject])
{
    BOOL isDirectory = NO;        
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",downloadsFolderString,file]
                                         isDirectory: &isDirectory];

            if (!isDirectory)
            {
                [fileList appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|", file]];
            }
}
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *timeOpened = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sessionID=%@&fileList=%@&dateTime=%@&userID=%@", sessionID, fileList, timeOpened, userID];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSString *comparisonURLString = SERVER_COMPARE_URL_STRING;
NSURL *comparisonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:comparisonURLString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:comparisonURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

if (responseData)
{
    NSString *requiredFilesList = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *lines = [requiredFilesList componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];        
    if (lines.count > 2)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            NSRange theRange;
            theRange.location = 2;
            theRange.length = [lines count] -3;
            numberOfFilesToBeDownloaded = theRange.length;

            if (numberOfFilesToBeDownloaded <= 0)
            {
                _jobStatusLabel.text = @"Documents up to date"; // is this the issue?
            }            
            if (numberOfFilesToBeDownloaded > 0)
            {
                NSArray *subArray = [lines subarrayWithRange:theRange];
                [self animateProgressBar];
                if (![eraseDevice isEqualToString:@"true"])
                {
                [self getFiles:subArray];
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"no response data from check files");
}
```

However, the `alertView` is not dismissed until the `checkFiles` method is complete. 
Can anyone tell me how to have the alert dismiss whilst `checkFiles` runs in the background?

Comment: what does `checkFiles:` actually do? it could be a case of what its doing is not thread safe (like changing UI elements in a background thread)

Comment: why are you saying "it didn't work"? can you post `checkFiles` code? what does it do and what should happen next ?

Comment: add a log in `checkFiles` and try it .

Comment: At least it hits the method for me after calling performSelectorInBackground, you need to be more precise.

Comment: @all: Thanks. Yes, just noticed `checkFiles:` tries to set a UILabel. I'll edit the original question.

Comment: Any UI work *must* be dispatched back to the main thread.  You can find examples of this double dispatch pattern in every corner of the internet, so have at it :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI operations should be done in the main thread.

For instance :

```
_jobStatusLabel.text = @"Documents up to date"; // is this the issue?
```

should be

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    _jobStatusLabel.text = @"Documents up to date"; // is this the issue?
});
```

change all such possible cases.

Comment: After a bit of tinkering, I'm making progress. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are updaing UI elemets from background thread. This would lead to unpredictable behavior. A better way to do this is like this -

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
     [self checkFiles:sessionID];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
         //breakup your checkFiles method to background tasks & UI tasks. Put UI updating 
         //code here which will get executed in the main thread.
     });
});
```

This is the GCD pattern of coding. Here it is asynchronous thread executes code synchronously. i.e.  after `checkFiles` finishes the next code (here its a async thread) gets executed.

You would need to break `checkFiles` method. Execute the HTTP part in the background thread and pass the parsed `responseData` to main UI thread. After that update the UI. See if this works...